# Raspberry Pi Proxy Settings don't work; Extra junk at end of file

Tags: linux, proxy, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm new to working with the Raspberry Pi and had some Problems connecting to the internet.

Since my Companys Ethernet is behind a Proxy I added 2 Files at:

etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy

etc/profile.d/proxy.sh

10proxy looks like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "{myproxy}:{port}";  
Acquire::https::proxy "{myproxy}:{port}";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "{myproxy}:{port}";
```

proxy.sh looks like:

```
export http_proxy=“{myproxy}:{port}”;
export https_proxy=“{myproxy}:{port}”;
export ftp_proxy=“{myproxy}:{port}”;

export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy;
export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy;
export FTP_PROXY=$ftp_proxy;
```

With these two files in place i still cant access the Internet.
When doing a

```
sudo apt-get update
```

i get an Error

```
Syntax ERROR: 10proxy:4: Extra junk at end of File
```

All the other similar questions i found were answered with: Put a semicolon after each line, but I habe semicolons there.

Thanks for any help!

Regards,
Felix